# trouble understanding this boost condition variable example

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, condition-variable

In the following example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable
what prevents the main() thread from calling cv.notify_one() prior to the worker_thread ever arriving at cv.wait()? It seems to me like the worker_thread could wait forever if the main() thread notifies early.

I expect to see a "while (!ready)" around "cv.wait()".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a wrapper loop with C++11 because it is already provided by the implementation of `wait`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

That is, `wait` will return immediately if lambda expression (this bit here: `[]{return ready;}`) evaluates to `true`.